# Using Docker-Compose to spin up multiple instances of a container with different configurations

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I understand that you can user docker-compose with the scale command to spin up multiple containers. However, they will all have the same configuration used.

Is it possible to launch a container on the same host with different configurations (different `.yml` files) on the same host?

Using the following commands:

```
docker-compose -f dev.yml up -d
docker-compose -f qa.yml up -d
```

only the `qa.yml` container will be running, which is not what I want.

-- **edit** --

Here's what happens when I try running both commands.

```
$ docker-compose -f compose/dev.yml up -d
compose_mydocker_1 is up-to-date
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
905912df6e48        compose_mydocker  "/sbin/my_init"     2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:1234->80/tcp   compose_mydocker_1
$ docker-compose -f compose/qa.yml up -d
Recreating compose_mydocker_1...
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
3fc912201224        compose_mydocker  "/sbin/my_init"     5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:1235->80/tcp   compose_mydocker_1
```

My `qa.yml` and `dev.yml` look like this:

```
mydocker: 
  build: ..

  ports:
    - "1234:80" #for dev.yml
   #- "1235:80" for qa.yml
  environment:
    - ENVIRONMENT=dev #and vice-versa for qa

  volumes:
    - ../assets/images:/var/www/assets
```

Comment: What happens when you run both commands? And side question: why you need both configurations to be run at the same time on the same host?

Comment: can you paste the log from the `dev` and `qa` docker-compose startup. if `dev` was run first, i would've expected `qa` to have died because of ports already in use.

Comment: I'll add the requested information to the question! @Opal : I want to run both environment on 1 server for testing purposes. "dev" is the environment the devs work on (can be broken), and "qa" is the environment QAs do tests on after a build makes it out of `dev`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you need to do is change the project name.  By default, compose uses a project named based on the current directory. In your case, you want separate environments, so you need different project names.

You can use either `docker-compose -p <project_name>` or set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` in the environment.

There is also some discussion about providing a way to persist the project name: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745

Comment: How to stop all containers in a project?

Comment: `docker-compose -p <project name> stop` or `docker-compose -p <project name> down`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323609/docker-compose-not-prepending-project-name-to-the-container-names-when-running-m