# Docker-compose shuts down container starting a different one

Tags: docker, docker-compose

to test our platform we have a preproduction machine that have 5 folders with the same repository (but different branch/state) in each one. Before docker compose, I deployed 5 containers (one from repository) from the same image. The main difference between container was the port.

But I changed from docker to docker-compose and now, if I make something like this:

```
cd ~/repo_at_8080/compose
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-container-name.yml up -d
docker ps
```

I get this result:

```
 server_http_8080
```

Then I try to start another container so I go to a different folder

```
cd ~/repo_at_8081/compose
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-container-name.yml up -d
docker ps
```

And then I do not get a list of 2 servers, but only the lsat one. Is there a way to start many machines in paralel? What I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Both your commands are in same folder `~/repo_at_8080/compose`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Docker-Compose to spin up multiple instances of a container with different configurations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939319/using-docker-compose-to-spin-up-multiple-instances-of-a-container-with-different)

Comment: Ya @dnephin, this post solves my problem. Thanks