# Docker compose not prepending project name to the container names when running multiple instances

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a set of docker that I run using `docker-compose up -d` pretty basic so far

I want to run multiple instances of my project and I have read this  [Run multiple docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957259/run-multiple-docker-compose)

Now when running `docker-compose up -p PRNAME -d` compose is not prepending project name to containers like `prname_container1` and I'm getting the following error :

```
ERROR: for container1  Cannot create container for service service1: Conflict. The container name "/container1" is already in use by container "f7aeb2ef782556ae5b0". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I might be missing something out here.

A part of my docker-compose.yml looks like

```
services:
  service1:
    image: "${PROJECT_REPO}:image"
    container_name: "container1"
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - db
      - proxy
      - oauth
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Can you add a sample minimal `docker-compose.yml` file to the question that shows the behavior you're describing?  (Are you manually specifying `container_name:`?)

Comment: Yes, I'm manually specifying container_name in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you explicitly set `container_name:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file, the container name will be *exactly* what you specify; Docker Compose won't add its per-directory prefix to it.

Usually this doesn't matter to you at all, and it's safe to remove `container_name:`.  You will still be able to reach other containers using their service name in `docker-compose.yml` as hostnames, and the `docker-compose` CLI provides wrappers for management commands like `docker-compose stop` that will act on the correct container.

You will also hit trouble with `ports:` and there is less of a clear solution here.  Only one container or process can bind to a specific port on the host.  You can leave off the first port number in `ports:`, and Docker will pick a port for you

```
ports:
  - '80'
  - '443'
```

but then you need to [manually look up the corresponding host port number](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/)

```
docker-compose port service1 80
```

Comment: Oh right, makes sense to me now THANKS ! I have already hit that trouble once with ports when trying to scale using --scale option but yes I'll have to let docker choose them for me.