# How to reuse docker-compose and have multiple instances up and running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm reusing my `docker-compose.yml` across my projects.

For example, I have a couple of API projects and for all of them I have created a central `docker-compose.yml` file inside a shared directory.

And I run `docker-compose -f /shared_path/api/docker-compose.yml up` to bring them up.

This works perfectly for each API that I want to work with. But the problem is that each API that I bring up, it exits the previous API automatically.

In other words, I can't run two or more APIs at the same time.

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

Here's my real `docker-compose.yml` that is being created dynamically.

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        image: holism/next-dev:latest
        container_name: ${Repository}NextDev
        ports:
            - "${RandomPort}:3000"
        working_dir: /${RepositoryPath}
        volumes: 
            - /HolismHolding/Infra:/HolismHolding/Infra
            - /HolismReact/Site:/HolismReact/Site
            - ${RepositoryPath}/components:${RepositoryPath}/components
            - ${RepositoryPath}/contents:${RepositoryPath}/contents
            - ${RepositoryPath}/pages:${RepositoryPath}/pages
            - ${RepositoryPath}/public:${RepositoryPath}/public
            - ${RepositoryPath}/styles:${RepositoryPath}/styles
            - ${RepositoryPath}/.env:${RepositoryPath}/.env
            - /Temp/${RepositoryPath}/Build:${RepositoryPath}/.next
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            cp -a /HolismReact/Site/. .
            && if [ ! -d ${RepositoryPath}/node_modules ]; then ln -s /site/node_modules ${RepositoryPath}; fi
            && npm run dev &
            echo -e '\033[0;31m'"http://localhost:$RandomPort"
            && tail -f /dev/null
            "
```

Comment: do you want scaling ? 
also what's the error ? is it because they all are listening to same port ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32956448/10161292) explains how to give project names to Docker Compose instances.

Comment: @MohsinAmjad, I don't want scaling. There is no error. As I explained, my other containe exits. They all reuse the same `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @boranseckin, that doesn't help me. Now I receive this error: `ERROR: for ProjectDev  Cannot create container for service site: Conflict. The container name "/ProjectDev" is already in use by container "182b78f369dd1870ee151c11cda288ba3332863d8225884656afce9d49cac280". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.`

Comment: You need to delete any manual `container_name:` and other `name:` assignments.  The other place you'll likely hit conflicts is with the published `ports:`; you also can't have multiple containers (or host processes) listening on the same host port.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I managed to assign ports dynamically. Why should I delete `container_name`?

Comment: @DavidMaze, container names are calculated dynamically too. I updated the question.

Comment: The error message you quote is because multiple containers (globally in the system) have the same `container_name:`; if you delete it, then Compose will generate a reasonably-unique name like `projectname_site_1` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the container_name as pointed out in the comments, and let docker-compose assign a name to the container according to the project name.

You could also use inheritance and create a different docker-compose file for each of your APIs to override port.

Your docker-compose.yml should look like this

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        image: holism/next-dev:latest
        working_dir: /${RepositoryPath}
        volumes: 
            ...
```

And you should create a docker-compose.api-1.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        - 1080:3000
```

And docker-compose.api-2.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        - 1081:3000
```

And then call

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.api-1.yml -p api-1 up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.api-2.yml -p api-2 up
```

So you'll end up with a container named `api-1_site` and another `api-2_site`, and you'll be able to access the first API on `localhost:1080` and the second one on `localhost:1081`